# Hba-a2 has two copies on UCSC genome browser

Tags: ucsc, genome-browser

I was browsering the UCSC viewer of the genome at [this region](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=mm10&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr11%3A32271127%2D32368934&hgsid=650939229_Ph2CmqBGLyApOC2IRsw66VU7fSYT).

UCSC genes label two genes as Hba-a2 while GENCODE thinks the left one is Hba-a1

Which annotation is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gencode is correct (when in doubt, always assume Gencode/Ensembl is correct when it differs from UCSC). What presumably happened is that the UCSC annotation pipeline noticed that Hba-a1 and Hba-a2 are nearly identical (they produce the same protein and have minimal nucleotide difference) and just misannotated.

Comment: As a general rule, it is usually safe to believe Gencode over RefSeq and RefSeq over UCSC (not because UCSC is bad, but because it isn't manually curated).